# Ubuntu One: Client for 10.10 has no "Cloud Folders" tab

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have Ubuntu 10.10 and I've seen somewhere about the "Cloud Folders" functionality of Ubuntu One, but I can't find it in my 10.10 version of the client. I updated my client but it's still the same basic tabs.

Can anyone please tell me if it's possible to have the "Cloud Folders" tab in my client? If not, is there any other way to have the same functionality without upgrading my Ubuntu version?

Thanks guys!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I answered the following similar question for Maverick & Ubuntu-one a little while ago:

- [ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk : Depends: ubuntuone-installer but it is not installable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66310/ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk-depends-ubuntuone-installer-but-it-is-not-install)

To summarise, the functionality you require is only available in the latest versions of the ubuntuone software.  The unstable nightly ubuntuone failed to build for maverick at that time.

Looking at the [latest situation](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/nightlies) today, the maverick PPA has now been removed - most probably because maverick is no longer supported.

As such - you will be unlikely to have the functionality in maverick without upgrading.